# PL/SQL call doesn't return entire varchar2 return value

Tags: c#, oracle

I wrote a procedure in PL/SQL. At the end of the procedure I have this:

```
    create or replace procedure Lottery_TitleBook(pout_count out varchar2) is
--get all the title-book.
cursor s1 is select * from gilads.titlebook;

rand Float;
randG VARCHAR2(100);
titleName VARCHAR2(100);
counter Number(38);
temp number(38);
res_row s1%rowtype; 

begin
 counter := 0;
 temp:=0;
--make random number generator:
randG := TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'YYYYDDMMHH24MISSFFFF');
DBMS_RANDOM.seed (val => randG);


--count how many title-book are in the cursor s1
open s1;
 loop
 fetch s1 into res_row;
 exit when s1%NOTFOUND;
 counter := counter +1;
 end loop;
close s1;

--the random number from  1 to counter 
rand := DBMS_RANDOM.value(low => 1, high => counter);

--get the titlebook.ID that determined by the random number:
open s1;
  loop
     fetch s1 into res_row;
     exit when s1%NOTFOUND;
     titleName := res_row.title;
   temp := temp + 1;
        if temp >= rand or temp = counter then exit;
        end if;
 end loop;
close s1;
--print the title book:
pout_count:='The winner book is:' ||chr(13)||titleName;

end;
```

When I call this from C# I get only "The winner boo". I have this problem with all my functions.

This is my C# code:

```
using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connect))
{
    string temp;
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;

    cmd.CommandText = "gilads.Lottery_TitleBook";//שם של פרוצדורה
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("pout_count", OracleType.VarChar, 3200).Direction =
      ParameterDirection.Output;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        int test = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (test == 1)
            textBlock.Text = cmd.Parameters["pout_count"].Value.ToString();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception Caught");
    }
```

When I set the size of the parameter to 32000 nothing changes. Any idea that is wrong? Maybe it has to do with oracle is on localhost ant there some setting i need to do? because in my University this code works properly

I noticed that every time I running the function i get a different length of string

Comment: VarChar2 is limited type: up to *4000* bytes in SQL https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm

Comment: That would be more than enough for those few characters @DmitryBychenko

Comment: I am using the managed client and your code works fine here.

Comment: Probably you have to work with `CLOB` / `NCLOB` or `LONG` (however, `LONG` is obsolete and not recommended)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko ... yes, but it isn't in plsql, which should be the only relevant context here - or am i missing something obvious ? (nb: as of 12c, 32k varchar2 may be used in sql too,though its internally represenetd like a lob, see [this note](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF55623) on extended data types from the oracle docs).

Comment: Can you show your entire procedure? Also, your code returns -1 here, might that cause a problem?

Comment: i dont know what to do any help??

Comment: Just because I have a bad feeling about that: Try it without `||chr(13)||`

Comment: i try it didn't help